# 302 and IO error in Uploadify

Tags: php, uploadify

Was working on image processing with uploadify on my local machine. but after another page refresh uploadify began to give me IO and  HTTP 302 errors.Any ideas? BTW tried to put into the .htaccess these directives

```
SecFilterEngine Off
SecFilterScanPOST Off
```

but after that it doesn't work at all(no swf button is diplayed, no autoupload on select). Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it sounds to me like the script inserted into the head is not pointed at the right files. Can you please post your script and also explain where the uploadify directory is in relation to your page?
for example if the location of your uploadify directory is at www.yourdomain.com/uploadify
and your page is stored at www.yourdomain.com/somedirectory/somefile.html, then you would have to backup in the directory location. The code below should help you. Also make sure your server will allow files to be uploaded to it.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../uploadify/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../uploadify/swfobject.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../uploadify/jquery.uploadify.v2.1.4.min.js">       </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
// <![CDATA[
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#file_upload').uploadify({
    'uploader'  : '../uploadify/uploadify.swf',
    'script'    : '../uploadify/uploadify.php',
    'cancelImg' : '../uploadify/cancel.png',
    'folder'    : 'somefolder',
    'auto'      : true,
  });
});
// ]]>
</script>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer.Found out that somehow script inserted additional headers to the page,removed that lines and it helped. But really don't get why it work before and then suddennly didnt.